# How to programmatically dismiss a Showcase view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using [showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package for displaying a message in a screen. It is dismissed when we click anywhere on the screen. But if the user came to that page and use the backbutton for going back, the showcase is not getting dismissed. Is there any way to dismiss the showcaseview other than touching the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
ShowCaseWidget.of(context).dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly think from what I got from your question that the show case view starts every time you go to that page, so you can pass a parameter to choose to show case view or not when open the page like :

```
 Navigator.push<void>(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<void>(
              builder: (_) => const Detail(showCaseView:false),
            ),
          );
```

and in Details screen where you use show case view :

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(isShowCaseView){
WidgetsBinding.instance
        ambiguate(WidgetsBinding.instance)?.addPostFrameCallback(
          (_) => ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
              .startShowCase([_one, _two, _three, _four, _five]),
        );
}
```